# leave only unique elements in a multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

How to make only unique values remain

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');

function super_unique($array,$key){
    $temp_array = [];
    foreach ($array as &$v) {
        if (!isset($temp_array[$v[$key]]))
        $temp_array[$v[$key]] =& $v;
    }
    $array = array_values($temp_array);
    return $array;

}

$arr = array();
$arr[0]['id'] = null; 
$arr[0]['name'] = 'John';

$arr[1]['id'] = 12; 
$arr[1]['name'] = 'John';

$arr[2]['id'] = null; 
$arr[2]['name'] = null; 

$arr[3]['id'] = 54; 
$arr[3]['name'] = 'Ammie'; 

$arr[4]['id'] = 23; 
$arr[4]['name'] = 'Martin'; 

$arr[5]['id'] = 54; 
$arr[5]['name'] = null; 

$arr[6]['id'] = 342; 
$arr[6]['name'] = 'Anna'; 

$arr[7]['id'] = 64; 
$arr[7]['name'] = 'Tom'; 

$arr[8]['id'] = 64; 
$arr[8]['name'] = null; 

$arr[9]['id'] = 364; 
$arr[9]['name'] = null; 

$arr[10]['id'] = null; 
$arr[10]['name'] = 'Piter'; 


$arr = super_unique($arr,'id');
$arr = super_unique($arr,'name');

$arr = array_values($arr);

echo json_encode($arr);

?>
```

I want to achieve such a result

```
[
    {
        "id": 12,
        "name": "John"
    },
    {
        "id": 54,
        "name": "Ammie"
    },
    {
        "id": 23,
        "name": "Martin"
    },
    {
        "id": 342,
        "name": "Anna"
    },
    {
        "id": 64,
        "name": "Tom"
    },
    {
        "id": 364,
        "name": null
    },
    {
        "id": null,
        "name": 'Piter'
    }
]
```

it doesn’t display the result to me with Peter and John gives the id as null

it is necessary that if the id is the same, then check by name and leave only one and without null, if the only value is null, then only leave null

like id's: 364
null name

and also for names
i expected john id to be 12

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can rewrite your unique method as following:

```
//This function will get you the missing field from the array:
function getField($arr, $key, $value, $newKey) {
    foreach($arr as $e)
        if (($e[$key] == $value) && $e[$newKey])
            return $e[$newKey];
}

$res = array();
foreach($arr as $a) {
    if (!$a["id"] && !$a["name"])
        continue; // if both null ignore
    if (!$a["id"]) // if id missing go get it
        $a["id"] = getField($arr, "name", $a["name"], "id");
    if (!$a["name"]) // fill the name if missing
        $a["name"] = getField($arr, "id", $a["id"], "name");
    $res[] = $a; // as to result array
}

$r = array_map("json_decode", array_unique(array_map("json_encode", $res))); // remove all duplicate elements
```

This will out print:

```
echo json_encode(array_values($r));

[{"id":12,"name":"John"},{"id":54,"name":"Ammie"},{"id":23,"name":"Martin"},{"id":342,"name":"Anna"},{"id":64,"name":"Tom"},{"id":364,"name":null},{"id":null,"name":"Piter"}]
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.
a happy new year and Merry Christmas